# Standard output when using multiple threads

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I am using eclipse, and when I run it normally I don't see a printed statement in the console, but when I run it in debug mode, I see it. What is going on?
This happens only with some print statements (on the server side of a server-client school project, both being run on local host).

```
private class GameDriver extends Thread { 
     private Board board; 

     public GameDriver() { 
        board = new Board(); 
     } 

     @Override 
     public void run() { 
         boolean twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined = false; 
         while (!twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined) { 
             twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined = connector.activePlayers.size() >= 2; 
         } 
         System.out.println("Two players already connected, ready to start game"); 
         sendBoardStateToAll(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: You should show the code for the printfs that's missing. Perhaps it's as easy as you're not writing a newline, thus the output is not flushed - and it doesn't appear when you expect it to.

Comment: '''private class GameDriver extends Thread {
  private Board board;
  public GameDriver() {
   board = new Board();
  }
  @Override
  public void run(){
   boolean twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined = false;
   while (!twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined) {
    twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined = connector.activePlayers.size() >= 2;
   }
   System.out.println("Two players already connected, ready to start game");
   sendBoardStateToAll();
  }
'''

Comment: Please add the code to your original question using the code sample syntax, this way it will be [more] readable.

Comment: Can somebody please edit my code comment? The funny thing is that if I add some other print statement, such as  while (!twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined) {
    twoActivePlayersAlreadyJoined = connector.activePlayers.size() >= 2;
    System.out.println("waiting for 2 people to connect...");
   }
then it works

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse debug window shows different JVMs started from your Eclipse instance.

[image: Eclipse Debug Windows showing the threads]

If you start more than one application in Eclipse, then there will be more than one JVM shown in the debug window as well. Now, if you select one of the JVMs in the debug window the output console changes to the selected JVM's standard output.

Without debug mode, however, Eclipse just displays the standard output of the JVM's console which has printed to standard output last.

Answer (score 0):

Q: I am using eclipse, and when I run it normally I don't see a printed statement in the console, but when I run it in debug mode, I see it. What is going on?

It's entirely possible for a "printf" written from a child thread to remain buffered until the thread is terminated.  In which case you'll never see it.

SUGGESTION:

Try "System.err.println()" instead.  This uses unbuffered I/O.  You might see *everything* you expect.

Comment: That makes sense, because the problem only happens where I have mutlithreading, but this didn't solve it. At least in the console I still don't see any output from the problematic statements. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`connector.activePlayers.size()` makes it look like `connector.activePlayers` is a collection. Is it a thread-safe collection? (And even if it's not a collection, is it it thread-safe?) If not, it could be that `connector.activePlayers.size()` is constantly returning `0` or `1`, resulting in your `while` loop spinning forever. If this is happening, you might be seeing CPU usage shoot up -- is that the case? Anyway, you can easily check by putting a `System.out.println("foo")` in the `while` loop.

It could well be that the debugger is inserting synchronization points or otherwise causing CPU registers, cache, etc to get flushed. That could explain why you're seeing the loop terminate (and thus the `System.out.println` output) in a debugger, but not in "normal" mode where the JVM is more aggressive about optimization.